# Non expected bytes with reading file by bytes using Java

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to read some file by bytes. The problem is that Java shows me not the same bytes, that I can read using Far hex editor.

Read bytes using Far:
00 00 00 17 00 00 00 29 00 00 00 99 00 00 00 9B

Read bytes using Java:
0 0 0 17 0 0 0 29 0 0 0 22 0 0 0 3a

Java code:

```
while ((line = (byte) _br.read()) != -1) {
    lines.add(line);
    System.out.println("lines = " + Integer.toHexString(line));
}
```

Comment: You are doing several implicit conversions here. What is the type of the lines list? I'm guessing the problem is with signed/unsigned overflow, since 9B and 99 is both over 127.

Comment: Thanks, t solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You are prematurely converting the integer returned by `read()` to byte. This causes an overflow and could prevent the -1 end of file check from working (on top of your current problem). The documentation it says the value returned is between 0 and 65535 (which can't be handled by a byte variable). In java, byte is signed 8-bit value so you'll have problems whenever a value is greater than 0x7F. Change the `line` variable type to int and try again.